# phpexcel duplicate formula just like excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm new with phpexcel and want to copy formula from one cell to others just like in excel.

My program reads data from an input file, and add some more rows in it before saving to a new file. The input sheet has some formula in cells, for example in cell C1, the formula is =A1*B1.

I want to generate more 1 row with the formula in C2 is A2*B2, this is just like copy&paste cell C1 to C2 in excel.

How can i do this with phpexcel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for this. You have to set the formula correctly for each cell, so you need to iterate over the cells where you set the formula modifying that formula for each row:

```
for ($row = 1; $row <= 10; ++$row) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue(
            'C' . $row, 
            '=A' . $row . '*B' . $row
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually i don't know what exactly the formula is in input file. Any method to parse the formula and generate new one for the next rows?

Comment: No, there is no simple shortcut.... although you could try using the `updateFormulaReferences()` method of the `PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper` class, which is used internally to manipulate formulae when inserting/deleting rows/columns

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have same task with you, so this is static method that I had added to PHPExcel_Calculation_Parser. Hope can help you :).

```
    /**
 * 
 * @param numeric $rowNumber
 */
public static function cloneFormulaForRow($formula, $rowNumber, $rowFlag = 1) {
    $formulaParser = new PHPExcel_Calculation_FormulaParser($formula);
    $tokens = $formulaParser->getTokens();
    $snips = [];

    foreach ($tokens as $token) {
        /* @var $token PHPExcel_Calculation_FormulaToken */
        $type = $token->getTokenType();
        $subType = $token->getTokenSubType();
        $val = $token->getValue();

        if ($type == 'Operand') {
            if ($subType == 'Range') {
                $cells = explode(':', $val);
                foreach ($cells as &$cell) {
                    $cell = preg_replace_callback('/^([a-z]+)' . $rowFlag . '$/i', function($m)use($rowNumber) {
                        return $m[1] . $rowNumber;
                    }, $cell);
                }

                $snips[] = implode(':', $cells);
            } else if ($subType == 'Text') {
                $snips[] = ('"' . $val . '"');
            } else {
                //number
                $snips[] = $val;
            }
        } else if ($type == 'Function' || $type == 'Subexpression') {
            if ($subType == 'Start') {
                $snips[] = '(';
            } else {
                $snips[] = ')';
            }
        } else if ($type == 'OperatorInfix') {
            $snips[] = $val;
        } else {
            $snips[] = $val;
        }
    }

    return '='. implode('', $snips);
}
```

Example:

```
PhpExcel_Calculation_Parser::cloneFormulaForRow("=SUM(A1:B1)",9) //"=SUM(A9:B9)"
```